# How to represent user interest in more sectors of same category?

Tags: sliders, categorization, graphs

I want to represent the user interests for particular subcategory of some category, to be concrete - let's say we want to track user interest for clothes and I want to see how much they're interested in buying shoes, jeans, jackets and so on. What I had in mind is to put [radar chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) and to implement it with multiple sliders for each subcategory. I'm not sure that's the best what's offering out there, because it has fixed amount of subcategories and it doesn't seem so neat.

Could you help me in this?

Comment: What have you got so far? Can you provide a wireframe? or some extra context? You'll probably get a better answer if you provide a better starting point. Who and what is this UI for? These categories and subcategories; are they fixed or can user create them, if so, how would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using vertical bars, they are more simple and comparisons are easy. See below :

[image: mockup]

Some additional suggestions :

- Do not use numbers or scale, accuracy in your case is not important, it will only create clutter.
- If possible, have fixed subcategories for each category. It is better to have subcategories with zero value, than to change the location of the bars for each customer.